# android:drawableRight vs android:drawableEnd

Tags: android, android-drawable

If I use `android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_image"`on a button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_button"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_image"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"/>
```

Then a warning/suggestion in editor tells me:

> Consider replacing `android:drawableRight` with
>   `android:drawableEnd="@drawable/my_image"` to better support
>   right-to-left layouts

What does this mean? Can you no longer use `android:drawableRight` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain countries' languages are read right to left. If you don't code your layout elements with this in mind, your app may not look correctly in their devices. Essentially, replace `left` with `start` & `right` with `end` in your layout elements. This applies to both the XML **attributes** & the **values** of said XML attributes. You can see the results & play around with your layouts under Right-to-Left conditions if you go under **Developer Options** & tap **Force RTL Layout**.

Here is an example of a layout I used recently. Pay careful attention to the use of **End** in both an **XML attribute** & as a **value** of an XML attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="end">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bid_price"
        style="@style/BidPriceTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        tools:text="1000.00" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/change"
        android:background="@drawable/percent_change_pill"
        style="@style/PercentChangeTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="3dp"
        tools:text="100%" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Daniel's answer **drawableEnd** and **drawableStart** can be used for **API_14**+. So if you are using **minSdkVersion < 14**, you must also use **drawableRight** and **drawableLeft** besides **drawableEnd** and **drawableStart**.